# Not able to update image path in my database

Tags: mysql

I m not able to update image path in my sql database in php. It  is not showing any error also.I want set profile picture of user(like facebook) so for that i had done coding but it is not working can any one help me in finding my error.

```js
profilepicture.php

<!-- Step 3-->

<?php

<?php
/**********MYSQL Settings****************/
$host="localhost";
$databasename="photo_db";
$user="root";
$pass="";
/**********MYSQL Settings****************/
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if($conn)
{
 $db_selected = mysql_select_db($databasename, $conn);
 if (!$db_selected)  
 {
  die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
 }
}
else
{     die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}




?>




    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;

       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
     default: return false;
  }
 }

 
 
 
if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"]))
 {
    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
 $imagename=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
 //$imagename=date("y-d-m")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "images/".$imagename;
 

     if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) 
  {
  
  
  $query_upload="UPDATE signup SET profilepicture='$target_path' WHERE uname='devansh@gmail.com' limit 1 " ;
  $qry=mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ".mysql_error()); 
  if(!$qry)
  {
   die("mySQL error: ". mysql_error());  
  }
  else
  {
   header("location:index.php");
  }
       
 }
  else
  {
  exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
  }
}
   ?>
```

```html
index.html

<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function performClick(node)
{
 var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
 evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
 node.dispatchEvent(evt);
 var theFile = document.getElementById("theFile");
 // the file is the first element in the files property


}
</script>
 </head>
  <body>
    
      

      <a href="profilepicture.php" onclick="performClick(document.getElementById('theFile'));">Edit</a>
 
      <input type="file" id="theFile" name="uploadedimage"  style="visibility:hidden;" /> 
       
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some blanks in your sql string:

```
    $query_upload="UPDATE signup".
    " SET profilepicture='$target_path'".
    " WHERE uname='devansh@gmail.com' limit 1 " ;
```

Your querystring generates:

```
UPDATE signupSET profilepicture=$target_pathWHERE uname='devansh@gmail.com' limit 1  ;
```

and that should give you a syntax error.

Comment: "UPDATE signup SET profilepicture=$target_path WHERE uname='devansh@gmail.com' limit 1"; this gives me and error::error in UPDATE signup SET profilepicture=images/Jellyfish.jpg WHERE uname='devansh@gmail.com' limit 1 == Unknown column 'images' in 'field list' @Jens

Comment: @namrata Have updated my answer. You have to put quotes around `$target_path` bacause it is a char field.

Comment: By adding qoutes error is not comming but by selecting image and pressing on edit button it gives me "no file choose" besides choose file button @Jens

Comment: @namrata I am glad to helped you. Please accept the answer if it is the solution.

Comment: Now one more problem has been arrise i m not able to update imge when i tried to use edit link instesd to browser button...By clicking on edit link file dialog opens and after selecting image pressing open button it is not working leads to error.

Comment: i had updated my code plz ckeck it out.. thanku @Jeans

Comment: @namrata I can not run the coe, so can you add the error message please?

Comment: error is not comming only that is it main problem...So i m aslo not able to get where i m getting wrong..I can just tell u that if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) returns true i,e it goes into else part and only shows "error" Just this much only @Jens

Comment: But the `else` is not an mysql error so you can/should  not do  `echo "error=".mysql_error();`.Can you check if `$_FILES["uploadedimage"]` is empty

Comment: Yes ofcourse it is empty that why it not only moving into if section..Though i m selecting image....